# How to make an ajax call on usercontrol onload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a usercontrol and I wrote a javascript method on its onload. The method is not called when the usercontrol is loaded.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HDDynControl.ascx.cs"     Inherits="HDPortalTestApp.HDDynControl" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HDDynControl_OnLoad() {
        debugger;
        alert("test");
    }
</script>
```

I don't want to do it in usercontrol.cs file as:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "test, "javascript:" + HDDynControl_OnLoad()", true);
```

Comment: how are you calling the method? can you post that part also to clearify more?

Answer (score 0):

Use can do this by this using javascript only.

var int=self.setInterval(functioName,1000);

function functioName()
{

```
// writeCode
// first time only
//window.clearInterval(int)
```

}